# Two branch merge

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

Suppose I got a file amended in two revisions, says 100, 110, in a **branch**. If I solely merge **110** to **trunk**, would the modification in **100** be brought over to **trunk** also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file revision **110** is a direct lineage of revision **100**, then it contains all changes made in 100. In that case, the answer is **Yes**, BUT in order to maintain a complete revision history, merge in **100** first and then **110**.

Answer (score 2):

If revision 100 was made after you branched source code, and you merged 110 (from the same branch as 100) to trunk, then yes, all changes included in 100 as well will be in trunk.